# What bulbs will do well planted in containers in the fall in Dallas, and how should I take care of them?

Tags: plant-recommendations, containers, bulbs

I'm a total and complete novice when it comes to gardening...

I'd like to plant some bulbs this fall in large containers on my back patio.  I live near Dallas, Texas.

What bulbs would you recommend?  And how should I care for them?

Answer (score 2):

A quick bit of research suggests that you are probably in zone 8 which has a minimum temp of around 15F.  Tulips and daffodils need about 40 days of weather below 45F in order to bloom well.  OTOH amarylis, alliums, fresias and anemones should all do well without the kind of chilling we get in the north.

I would find a good garden store and engage one of the staff and see what they recommend.  You might also try going for a walk on a street where people are growing gardens and see what they do.  Gardening is about experimenting so don't feel bad if everything you try doesn't do well.

(If I could live in a place where amarylis would grow outside I am pretty sure that would be all I would grow.  I don;t want that bad enough to move to zone 8, but you should consider yourself lucky.)